# Chrome extension have background script wait until tab operation is complete

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that needs the current window in focus in order to submit a form. This form submission can take a few seconds and I don't want the tab to switch to the next form submission even if another tab calls `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`

```
// content_script.js

if (!Document.visibilityState === ""visible) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage("Focus", function(resp) {
    reply_link.click()
    setTimeout(function() {
      // from here, let the background script know it's OK to continue
      // if background.js tries to call another tab from here it is blocked from doing so
    }, 1000)
  })
}


// background.js

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
  chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {"active": true}, function(tab){
    return sendResponse(tab)
  });
  return true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the time to wait in the same message so the background script can manage the queue inside:

content_script.js

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'focus', wait: 1000}, response => {
  reply_link.click()
});
```

background.js

```js
const queue = [];

const ACTIONS = {

  focus(task) {
    chrome.tabs.update(task.sender.tab.id, {active: true}, tab => {
      task.response = tab;
      callOrWait(processQueue, task.msg.wait);
    });
    return true;
  },

};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  queue.push({msg, sender, sendResponse});
  return queue.length > 1 || processQueue();
  // returning 'true' postpones the response thus pausing the sender when there is 
  // already a task in the queue and once that completes this one will be processed
});

function processQueue() {
  while (queue.length) {
    const task = queue.shift();
    if ('response' in task) {
      task.sendResponse(task.response);
      continue;
    }
    const action = ACTIONS[task.msg.action];
    if (action && action(task) === true) {
      // this task wants an asynchronous response 
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
function callOrWait(fn, wait, ...args) {
  if (wait) {
    setTimeout(fn, wait, ...args);
  } else {
    fn(...args);
  }
}
```